# UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have used UICollection view to show items in grid layout.

For data source I have use 5*5 dimensional array.

And also I am returning 5 for numberOfItems in section and 5 for numberOfSections.

Then also my app is getting crashed with following error:

'UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 5}'

```
//////===viewcontroller.m==///////
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.theData = @[@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5"], @[@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10"],@[@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15"],@[@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20"],@[@"21",@"22",@"23",@"24",@"25"]];
    MultpleLineLayout *layout = [[MultpleLineLayout alloc] init];
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
    self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[DataCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DataCell"];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 5;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DataCell *cell = [collectionView  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DataCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label.text = self.theData[indexPath.section ][indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // UICollectionViewCell *item = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);

}
///////////////////////
```

Can anyone solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue in `MultpleLineLayout`? Is that a layout you wrote?

Comment: @KyleTruscott Thanks, you were correct it was an issue related to multiplelinelayout.

Comment: In my case I returned wrong the number of items on the method:                      
      
    collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)

For example: I had 9 items in my object but I returned 18... and the error was something like this "length = 8, path = 0 - 18" but this appeared here because I use a custom collectionViewLayout.

    collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MultipleLineLayout was originally written for infinite scrolling, so there was a problem with that implementation for your use. It should look like this,

```
-(NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    NSMutableArray* attributes = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSInteger i=0 ; i < self.collectionView.numberOfSections; i++) {
        for (NSInteger j=0 ; j < [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:i]; j++) {
            NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:j inSection:i];
            [attributes addObject:[self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        }
    }
    return attributes;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day. I was trying to do grid using uitableview but it became very difficult.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case others find this question with Google - I received the same error with a very interesting index path:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received
>   layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist:
>    {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'

I had simply forgotten to connect the collection view's data source and delegate to the view controller in Interface Builder. D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
    collectionView.reloadData()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

It comes because of the cache of the Cell's Autolayout when reloadData.